# Excel "Cannot Open PivotTable Source" error when opening directly to Excel from DL

Tags: excel, download, pivot-table

I have a website that generates some Excel spreadsheets and provides a download link to the end-user.  One of these spreadsheets is a fairly convoluted one with multiple charts based on multiple pivot tables.

For a few of our users, when they choose to "Open" the file immediately (as opposed to "Save As" to put it in a known path), we are running into problems when trying to refresh the pivot tables:

Cannot open PivotTable source file: 'C:\Users\joeuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\Content.ie5\W9IZXYBM[excel_file_name.xlsm]PivotTableSourceSheetName'

If the user chooses "Save" instead of "Open", the refresh works fine, so our users have a workaround, but can anyone shed light on what might cause only a few users to have this problem with the "Open" scenario?   We haven't spotted anything glaringly different between machines that "Open" the file just fine and those that don't.  Same browser versions, same Office versions, etc.

Comment: What is the data source of the PivotCache?  Is it an Excel range or a RecordSet?

Comment: It's an Excel range (on a worksheet that's within the same workbook as the pivottables/charts.  No external data sources muddying the water.)

Answer (score 0):

## Code:

```
Sub LinkBreaker()
    Dim Links() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Links = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(1)

    If Not IsEmpty(Links) Then
        For i = 1 To UBound(Links)
            ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=Links(i), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

## Theory:

This code will convert all external links in the worksheet into their values.  I think that this will eliminate your problem with the external file.  You should put this code in the Workbook_Open event.

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot open PivotTable source file: 'C:\Users\joeuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\Content.ie5\W9IZXYBM[excel_file_name.xlsm]PivotTableSourceSheetName'

The file referenced in error is an xlsm (macro enabled xlsx). This may cause issue. "Open" opens file in IE cache folder treated as internet content, it should have sth to do with the restrictions MSO imposed on internet oriented content. "Save"ed file are local file, which don't suffer from those restrictions. Considering the difference. Maybe change to xlsx ? Besides that I don't think there is anything you can do to circumvent it.